# Displaying row number in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to have the column "TASK #" to display the row number, but it always gets the value 0. What am I doing wrong?:

```
        public void LoadTasksTable()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            int index = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in tasksDT.Rows)
            {
                index = i;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK #"].Value = i;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK TYPE"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK TYPE"].Value;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["KEYWORD"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["KEYWORD"].Value;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["LINK"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["LINK"].Value;
                dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PROFILE"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PROFILE"].Value;
                i++;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }


tasksDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Tasks", connection);
        tasksDA.Fill(tasksDT);
        dataTasks.DataSource = tasksDT;
```

Comment: where is dataTasks created and displayed? also, what exactly do you expect this line to do? dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value;

Comment: this code is not the real code is it ? It loop on a different datatable and use another one to set it's own values to itself. Lot's of wrong structure here. If it's the real code then `tasksDT.Rows` has only 1 row.

Comment: sorry, very new to c#, updated my answer. Hopefully that helps. I meant to have those lines commented out to, sorry. @Broom

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void LoadTasksTable()
{
    try
    {
        int index = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < tasksDT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK #"].Value = i;
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PLATFORM"].Value;
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK TYPE"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["TASK TYPE"].Value;
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["KEYWORD"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["KEYWORD"].Value;
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["LINK"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["LINK"].Value;
            dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PROFILE"].Value = dataTasks.Rows[i].Cells["PROFILE"].Value;

        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I am guessing that using a normal for loop should do the trick.This is not tested, but it should work!! I hope this helps

Comment: I get the error 'DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Length'. Also I don't think the line "int i = 0;" should be there so I deleted. Thank you for the responce though, any solution to this?

Comment: Ok, I think it is Count in this case and not Length. I have edited the answer for you

Comment: I tried chaniging it to "5" and it still says 0, maybe there is an error somewhere else/?

Comment: when you say it "says 0", where do you see it saying this?